# Cooling NVME drive in laptop

Tags: cooling

I´m thinking of upgrading my NVME drive of my Asus ZenBook Duo. I was thinking of upgrading it with a Samsung Evo 980 Pro 1TB. I use my laptop for all kind of tasks (also editing videos, rendering etc. but not like crazy...). So I was wondering, how I keep the drive in a good temperature (mainly the controller).

I was thinking of a thermal pad as cooling support. I was reading several times that the Samsung Evo 980 Pro tend to get warmer than other drives.

The label of the Evo 980 Pro seems to have a cooling effect. Should I remove the label still or add a thermal pad on the label?

Sadly the Samsung [product-page](https://www.samsung.com/us/business/support/owners/product/980-pro-series-1tb/) doesn´t contain a manual, where I could try to figure something like that out.... ("Unfortunately, this information isn't currently available for this product."). I found couple of information's on other sites (but mainly other drives...), but I´m looking for someone, where does have some experience with the Evo 980 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the label. If it assists cooling, it should transfer the heat to the outer heat sink (normally air or something built into the motherboard). If you want your laptop chassis to be the ssd heatsink, you can add a thermal pad on top of the ssd. BTW, that is also how some modders made Macbooks a lot faster (M1 and intel based)